# Don't call function if argument is not a number

Tags: swift, int

I am new to programming. I've been following tutorials to learn Swift.

I have finished an app by following a tutorial but both the tutor's app and mine have an error.

This basic app adds a number to itself. It works great for the most part and is finished. However, when I entered a character instead of a number, it crashed. How can I check the value is a number before it runs the function?

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func onPlayBtn(sender: UIButton) {


    if whatTxt.text != nil && whatTxt.text != ""{

        playBtn.hidden = true
        logo.hidden = true
        whatTxt.hidden = true

        sumBtn.hidden = false
        sumTxt.hidden = false

        resetLbl()
        maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text!)!
        currentTimes = 0

       here is the line of code I know is checking that the box is not empty, it doesn't run the function if it is empty.
```

I thought maybe I could just add in  && `whatTxt.text != Int`, but that didn't work, and I think i have the wrong idea of what Int may be in that case.

Comment: Try to use a formatter for the input field

Comment: thank you all.... this answer solved the problem for me.    @IBAction func onPlayBtn(sender: UIButton) {
        
    guard let whatText = whatTxt.text, _ = Int(whatText) else { return }
        
       
        
        if whatTxt.text != nil && whatTxt.text != ""{
           
            
            playBtn.hidden = true
            logo.hidden = true
            whatTxt.hidden = true
            
            sumBtn.hidden = false
            sumTxt.hidden = false
     
            resetLbl()
            maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text ?? "") ?? 0
            currentTimes = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** force unwrap. You can use nil coalescing with the default values (probably `""` and `0`):

```
maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text ?? "") ?? 0
```

You can't check if it's not a number before running the function (the action will always be triggered) however if you **really** want to avoid the code from running just unwrap the value in a `guard`:

```
@IBAction func onPlayBtn(sender: UIButton) {

    guard let whatText = whatTxt.text,
          whatValue = Int(whatText) else { return }

    ...
    // The rest of the code goes here, no if necessary

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response, I no longer get an error if i moment out the  guard let whatText = whatTxt.text,
          whatValue = Int(whatText) else { return } section but if i click the button it goes in to do the math with all 0s when i uncomment the text after the function you suggested it says whatValue is never used value consider removing.

Comment: so when i click fix on the error it wants to change whatValue to    _  as seen below. but it now works it will not go into the math screen if a letter is entered.
        
    guard let whatText = whatTxt.text, _ = Int(whatText) else { return }

            resetLbl()
            maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text ?? "") ?? 0
            currentTimes = 0

Comment: @TonyMerritt you have to use either the nil coalescing or the guard. If you chose to you the guard just use set maxTimes to whatValue

Comment: ah ok I see, Thank you again @fpg1503

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use NSCharacterSet and rangeOfCharacterFromSet to understand if a string contain numbers:

```
var textFieldValue = "HELLO" // This should be the value from your textfield
let decimalCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
let rangeResult = textFieldValue.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(decimalCharacters, options: NSStringCompareOptions(), range: nil)

if rangeResult != nil {
    // Contain numbers
} else {
    // Not contain numbers
}
```

Another approach would be to use Regex pattern.

Comment: Just look at page 71 in Swift programming language manual. You can treat a String "12345" as possibleNumber with optionals

Comment: thank yo for your response. on this this answer lost me, sorry shows how new i am to this. when i added the code it found problems with my WhatTxt.txt being visible

Answer (score 1):

The crash occurs here `maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text!)!`. The `Int()` initializer returns an `Int?` (`Optional<Int>`) to represent that the `String` to `Int` conversion can fail (as you've been experiencing). The crash occurs when that initializer returns `nil`, but you try to force unwrap it with `!` anyway.

Instead, unwrap it safely:

```
@IBAction func onPlayBtn(sender: UIButton) {


    if let text = whatTxt.text where !text.isEmpty { //see note below

        playBtn.hidden = true
        logo.hidden = true
        whatTxt.hidden = true

        sumBtn.hidden = false
        sumTxt.hidden = false

        resetLbl()

        if let maxTimes = Int(text) {
            //text represents a valid Int, now available as the Int "maxTimes"
        }
        else {
            //text does not represent a valid Int
        }

        currentTimes = 0
```

Note: do not check for `nil` (`whatTxt.text != nil`) then force unwrap (`whatTxt.text!`). Instead, use an `if let` binding to safely unwrap: `if let text = whatTxt.text`

As a side note, try to avoid things names like `lbl`, `btn`, `txt`. `label`, `button`, `text` isn't that much longer, and it saves your code from looking like it's written by an edgy teenager in t3x+sp3@k

Comment: Thank you for your time on this i couldn't get this to work because when i added the code it came back with an error that maxTimes was never usedt if let maxim = Int(text) and wants me to change it to  if Int(text) != nil {

Comment: also what to thank you for your side note comment I will use full words in future. I was doing the same as the outer in the tutorial. thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all this answer solved it by not going to the math screen when a letter was entered. thanks go to jpg1503

@IBAction func onPlayBtn(sender: UIButton) {

```
guard let whatText = whatTxt.text, _ = Int(whatText) else { return }



    if whatTxt.text != nil && whatTxt.text != ""{


        playBtn.hidden = true
        logo.hidden = true
        whatTxt.hidden = true

        sumBtn.hidden = false
        sumTxt.hidden = false

        resetLbl()
        maxTimes = Int(whatTxt.text ?? "") ?? 0
        currentTimes = 0
```

Comment: Please don't post your own answer as a duplicate of somebody else's. Suggest an edit to theirs and accept theirs.

Comment: This is kind of a mess: you use a guard to make sure `whatTxt.text` isn't `nil`, then you use an `if` statement to check that `whatTxt.text` isn't nil, then you use `nil coalesce` (`whatTxt.text ?? ""`) anyway.

Comment: sorry about the repost. Thank you again for the advice, all the best

Comment: You have three options: guard and then use the unwrapped value, conditionally unwrap or use nil coalesce. You are using the three (you're not conditionally unwrapping but you're check if `whatTxt.text` is not `nil`). Just replace `_` with `whatValue` (or a better name), remove the if and set `maxTimes` to `whatValue`.